# Pfont ignores font weight

Tags: processing

I'm attempting to load a font (Gotham) to use in my sketch and it seems to be ignoring the font weight. The font is an .otf font. Comparing with what I see in illustrator it seems all weights of the font display as "medium."

I've tried creating a .vlw in processing and I have tried using the createFont() method. Both produce the same results.

```
PFont myFont;

void setup(){
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  size(500, 200);
  String[] fontList = PFont.list();
  println(fontList);
  myFont = createFont("Gotham-ExtraLight", 32);
  textFont(myFont);

  text("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 10,50);
}
```

Comment: what happens when you use textSize() manually ?

Comment: also you don't need the Sting Array in your code anymore...

Comment: When I use textSize() no change at all occurs. Perhaps this is unrelated but when I try textSize(0) I get an error. Part of the error message reads: Problem createFont(Lucida Sans). I'm not trying to use Lucida here so perhaps it's pulling the wrong font?

Comment: Hm weird. Well, fontSize(0) should give an error I think.. but thats a weird error message...

Comment: What version of Processing are you using ?

Comment: 2.2.1 on OSX Mavericks

Comment: When you `println` list of supported fonts is your "Gotham-ExtraLight" present? And when I try to set `textSize(0)` it don't give me a error. You can try to export your font as `.ttf` or `.otf` in your sketch data directory ... it may help.

Comment: Yes, "Gotham-ExtraLight" is listed. I actually copied the text directly from the output. I have tried the same thing with several of the other fonts listed but I get the same behavior.